# Spring WS tutorial: no declarationcan be found for element 'context:component-scan' error

Tags: web-services, spring-ws, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, servlets

I'm following step-by-step (basically copying and pasting stuff) this [spring-ws](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/tutorial.html) tutorial and I just hit a wall when configuring the *spring-ws-servlet.xml* as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.hr"/>

    <sws:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

Adding the following line:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.hr"/>
```

make STS starts yelling at me that:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict,
but no declarationcan be found for element 'context:component-scan'.
```

I don't know how to proceed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add:
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd

to the schemaLocation.

Comment: Oh well, I guess also copying and pasting might get over complicated at certain hours... Thanks!